# Probability - Geometric Sequence Problem

Tags: probability

I have been trying to solve a problem which states the following:

For every hour less than 8, an initial value depreciates by 7.9%. The initial value given is 87. This is what I have calculated so far:

8 hours = 87 
7 hours = 80.127 
6 hours = 73.797 
5 hours = 67.967 
4 hours = 62.598 
3 hours = 57.652 
2 hours = 53.098 
1 hours = 48.903

From the above, it can be seen that the problem is a geometric sequence, having a constant ratio of 0.921.

The problem asks to find the number of hours it would take to reach 50. I know that multiplying a previous value by 0.921 gives you the next value for a whole hour (bottom to top). However, I am really struggling to find a way to calculate the hours for the value 50. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Starting at $0$ hours, rather than 8 hours, the formula for the value $V$ after $h$ hours is $V = 87*0.921^h $

Rearrange this formula to find the number of hours to produce a value $V=50$ (Hint: the rearrangement involves logarithms)

Comment: @ArthurVause Thank you. Can you provide me with a link or details on how you got to this formula? If you can include it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each hour, the value $V$ is multiplied by 0.921 (i.e. losing 7.9%).

So after $h$ hours, the value is the initial value, $87$, multiplied by $0.921$, h times:

$V = 87 * 0.921 * 0.921 *...  * 0.921 $ ($h$ occurences of $0.921$)

This can be written as $V = 87 * 0.921^h $, and the formula works for fractional values of $h$ as well as for whole numbers.

Rearrange this formula by taking logarithms of both sides
(noting that $log(A*B)=log(A)+log(B)$ and $log(A^C) = C*log(A) $ )

So:    $log(V) = log(87) + h*log(0.921)$

You can then substitute in the value $V=50$ to solve for $h$